# Grabbing and Changing Kendro DropDownList index in JS Injection

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm working on a chrome extension script to use JavaScript to auto fill in some forms for me. Using Scripty for the extension.

Currently trying to change the index of a kendoDropDownList. I can't seem to find the the correct element to grab or clone the websites own JS to cause this to happen.

Here's what I've currently tried. Read through all the Kendo API the Best I could. I commented in the errors thrown into the code. I have the script spamming every second to handle window changes and multiple pages at once.

```
    var dropDownList = document.getElementById("DocumentType");
    if (!dropDownList) {
        console.log("Could not find Document Type Drop Down List");
        return;
    } // Gets to here just fine. 
    dropDownList.select(5); // Does not throw error, but does nothing
    var dataVar = dropDownList.data("kendoDropDownList"); // Throws exception ".data( is not a function"
    if (!dataVar) {  // Haven't gotten this var down the method. 
        console.log("Element did not contain data set.");
        return;
    }
    if ((dropDownList.data("kendoDropDownList").index()) != 5) {
        console.log("Changing index of drop down list to Identiy Proof.").
            dropDownList.data("kendoDropDownList").select(5);
    }
```

I'm not familiar enough with JS to understand why I can't inject using $("Variable name") to find things like I can in the console, but this is what works in the console and the website itself uses to grab the element and mess with it. I can use that and .select(5) in the console just fine.

```
$("#DocumentType").data("kendoDropDownList").select(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up vanilla JS with jQuery. It's important to understand that jQuery(the code you run in console) is a JS library, but the code you're trying in your script is only JS. That means that jQuery's functions are not available the way you're using in your script.

This code `document.getElementById("DocumentType");` return a DOM element, which doesn't has the `.data()` method. That method belongs to jQuery. That is why one code works and other doesn't, they're different.

Use the same code in your script and it will probably work, since jQuery is required for kendo to work, it would probably be available in your script as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a backend guy.; mostly Java and C++ for embedded systems. I hate JS with a passion. I've tried a few things with no luck. I did try to run the same code in my injections with no luck. I've found no real good guides on matching the libraries I import to my injection code with the same libraries at the website. I know there is some "scope" thing with JS, but the libraries are mentioned in the <head>, so I figured injected code would pull from the available libraries. But no luck there either.

Comment: @C_States everyone hates JS until they start to understand it hahaha. But you're not having problems with JS but with Web stack instead. That could be kinda complex for people who are used to work with one laguange at time. Anyway, I dont understand the problem in your comment. What i said in my answer is that both codes you are using should work in your script, but they are different.  You should keep using the one you tried in console as Kendo UI is based on jQuery(and that's what youre using in that code). Now if you CAN'T import jQuery to your script, then you have to use pure JS.